# Will this create a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Say I have a Fragment and in my Fragment I do this:

```
resultAdapter = new ResultAdapter(this, search);
listView.setAdapter(resultAdapter);
```

and the constructor of my adapter is:

```
public ResultAdapter(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment; 
}
```

My Fragment then holds a reference to the adapter and the adapter holds a reference to the fragment. 
Would this prevent the GC to collect both om them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it wouldn't. When your fragment will be detached from activity and destroyed it will lost reference to the GC root. So it's definitely ok.